# Getting user data in NewProjectCreationPage in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I have been successful in making a plugin. However now i need that on project creation page i add some more textboxes to get the user information. Also i need to use this information to add into the auto generated .php files made in project directory.

I want to know how can i override the `WizardNewProjectCreationPage` to add some more textboxes to the already given layout. I am pretty new to plugin development. Here is the code for my custom wizard.

```java
import java.net.URI;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExecutableExtension;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog;
import org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewProjectCreationPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard;

import rudraxplugin.pages.MyPageOne;

import rudraxplugin.projects.RudraxSupport;

public class CustomProjectNewWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard, IExecutableExtension {
    private WizardNewProjectCreationPage _pageOne;
     protected MyPageOne one;
    private IConfigurationElement _configurationElement;
    public CustomProjectNewWizard() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setWindowTitle("RudraX");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        super.addPages();

        _pageOne = new WizardNewProjectCreationPage("From Scratch Project Wizard");
        _pageOne.setTitle("From Scratch Project");
        _pageOne.setDescription("Create something from scratch.");
        addPage(one);

        addPage(_pageOne);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
         String name = _pageOne.getProjectName();
            URI location = null;
            if (!_pageOne.useDefaults()) {
                location = _pageOne.getLocationURI();
                System.err.println("location: " + location.toString()); //$NON-NLS-1$
            } // else location == null
            RudraxSupport.createProject(name, location);
            // Add this
            BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.updatePerspective(_configurationElement);

            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config,
            String propertyName, Object data) throws CoreException {
        _configurationElement = config;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Ask for any other code required. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `WizardNewProjectCreationPage` directly create a new class extending `WizardNewProjectCreationPage` and override the `createControl` method to create new controls:

```java
class MyNewProjectCreationPage extends WizardNewProjectCreationPage
{
   @Override
   public void createControl(Composite parent)
   {
     super.createControl(parent);

     Composite body = (Composite)getControl();

     ... create new controls here   
   }
}
```